# Vue3 Composite API window.scrollTo element of ref Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

Anybody an idea how to get the offsetTop of an element in Vue3 with the composite API? Like this version of Vue2?

```
goto(refName) { 
  var element = this.$refs[refName];
  var top = element.offsetTop;     
  window.scrollTo(0, top);
}
```

i have in my setup():

```
const accordions = ref([]);
...
<Disclosure
    v-slot="{ open }"
    v-for="(region, index) of data"
    :key="index"
    :ref="(el) => pushToRef(el, index)"
  >...</Disclosure>

function pushToRef(el, index) {
  accordions[index] = el;
}
```

it is filled by elements of a v-for. I could get the proxy out of the array later. But not the offset:

```
const element = accordions[region]; 
console.log("Region: " + region); //got the name 
console.log("Element: ", element); // Proxy of element 
const top = element.offsetTop; // UNDEFINED ???
console.log("OffsetTop: " + top); // !!! Undefined 
window.scrollTo({ top: top, left: 0, behavior: "smooth", });
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your code is running before the component is mounted.
Try wrapping it in a `onMounted`

```js
import { onMounted } from 'vue'

onMounted(() => {
  const element = accordions[region];
  const top = element.offsetTop;
  console.log("OffsetTop: " + top);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you meant to mutate `accordions` as it's a ref object but if you are doing that in your actual code, you should avoid it and mutate the inner value instead i.e `accordions.value`.
Now, since `Disclosure` is a component and not an HTML element, vue's template ref won't refer to that element's DOM. It will refer to Vue Instance of the `Disclosure` component instead. You can read more on that [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#ref-on-component).
You need to access the HTML element's DOM like this: `el.$el`, then you can access all DOM properties including `offsetTop`.
In case you want to check all properties of a component instance, you can find them [here.](https://vuejs.org/api/component-instance.html#component-instance)
Side note: This ref behavior is same in Options API as well i.e you will access DOM properties of a vue component in a similar way like this: `this.$refs['REF_NAME'].$el`